# Kotlin\Java - How to get sum of changed Array elements

Tags: java, kotlin

I have an array of prices which are Strings and look like this "$100.00". 
I want to check the sum of all those prices but before I need to change String to number, I did it like this:

```
val price2 = "$100.00"
val price3 = "INCLUDED"
val price4 = "$200.00"
val prices: Array<String> = arrayOf(price2, price3, price4)
```

Here's how I change String to Float:

```
 for (s: String in prices) {
            //I replace all dollar signs to empty space
            val s1 = s.replace("$", "")
            //I replace Included price to 0
            val s2 = s1.replace("INCLUDED", "0")
            //Change type to float
            val p = s2.toFloat()
            println(p)
        }
```

How to find the sum of all those changed elements? I mean, I want the sum of 100.0 + 0.0 + 200.0. 
Things I tried:

```
//added this into for loop  
val sum = +p
println(sum)
```

Or

```
 //I tried to put this into the loop and after it
 val x = prices[0] + prices[1] + prices[2]
 println(x)
```

Thanks for any help! I've been trying to write in Kotlin but Java examples will be fine.

EDIT: I've been thinking to add p to a new Array maybe and then find the sum of the 2nd Array but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: What do you get with the two code versions you tried?

Comment: @TedHopp, with `val sum = +p` I got the same as just `println(p)` - just a list of elements, like 100.0, 0.0, 200.0.

Comment: How do you initialize `sum`?

Comment: @TedHopp, and with `val x = prices[0]...` I got just $100.00, INCLUDED, $200.00. So it prints elements without changes.

Comment: @TedHopp, I just create `val sum = +p` inside for loop :) I think that's the cause? :)

Comment: Try initializing `sum` to zero before the loop and printing `sum` after the loop exits.

Comment: Didn't work, it says that `sum` is never used inside the loop.

Comment: I wasn't clear. use `sum += p` inside the loop (just after `val p = s2.toFloat()`).

Comment: I already did that. It just prints all the elements, not their sum. I tried to create `sum` val\var outside of loop or even function but it says that `val sum` is never used inside the loop.

Comment: You may also want to read [Java Practices -> Representing money](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=13). You probably should be using `BigDecimal` instead of `Float`.

Comment: @mfulton26, thanks for your advice! Since all the prices are ending with '.00' that is not that bad for me but gonna change to `BigDecimal` anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more down-to-the-ground solution:

```
val prices = listOf(price2, price3, price4)
val pricesParsed = prices.map {it.replace("$", "")}.map {it.toFloatOrNull() ?: 0f}
println(pricesParsed.sum())
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I get `Error: Kotlin: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
@JvmName public fun Iterable<Byte>.sum(): Int defined in kotlin.collections
@JvmName public fun Iterable<Double>.sum(): Double defined in kotlin.collections
@JvmName public fun Iterable<Float>.sum(): Float defined in kotlin.collections
@JvmName public fun Iterable<Int>.sum(): Int defined in kotlin.collections...`

Comment: Sorry about that. I forgot to use the float zero `0f`. With it all works as expected

Comment: Also not that it is recommended to use lists instead of arrays. They have the same performance, but much more functionality

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var sum = 0
for (s: String in prices) {
        //I replace all dollar signs to empty space
        val s1 = s.replace("$", "")
        //I replace Included price to 0
        val s2 = s1.replace("INCLUDED", "0")
        //Change type to float
        val p = s2.toFloat()
        println(p)
        sum += p // NO var keyword!
}
println(sum)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped :) I got your idea from the comments but when I also moved `+` from `p` to `=` it worked. Thanks again :)

Comment: Probably you intended to declare `sum` as `var`, rather than `val`, otherwise you can't reassign it later.

Comment: @Ilya - Yep. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

Can go with this also:

```
var p:Float = 0.0f
for(i :String in prices) {
   var s1 =   i.replace("$","")
   var s2 = s1.replace("INCLUDED","0")
   p  = p + s2.toFloat()
}
```

Comment: You really need to take care of formatting your code. This is very hard to read.